# F# - Create Expr by hand

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a `Expr<'a -> string` by hand, and after several hours reading and trying I give up..

However, I did figure out how to write the C# version:

```
let buildExpression<'a> =
    let p = E.Parameter(typeof<'a>)
    E.Lambda<F<'a,string>>(p)
```

which will produce:

`Expression<Func<'a, string>>`

So my question is, how do I create a `Expr<'a -> string>` by using the `Expr` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# sample is a bit suspicious, if you called `buildExpression<int>`, then the result would be an expression (in the C# sytnax): `Func<int, string>(x => x)`, which has a wrong type. I guess C# doesn't check types at construction time, but if you tried compiling it, it would probably crash.

I guess you want to build something like `x => x.Foo`. Then the following snippet should do the trick:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type Foo() =
  member x.Prop = "hello"

// Create a new variable 'x'
let arg = Var.Global("x", typeof<Foo>)
// Use Reflection to get information about the 'Prop' member
let propInfo = typeof<Foo>.GetProperty("Prop")
// Create a lambda 'fun x -> x.Prop'
let e = Expr.Lambda(arg, Expr.PropertyGet(Expr.Var(arg), propInfo))
```

Comment: Perfect! `e` will return `Expr` in your example, how would I have it return `Expr<Foo -> string>` instead?

Comment: `Expr.Cast` should do it. But be careful with it! You can cast `<@@ 4 @@>` to `Expr<string>`, and the error will appear only during run-time (and not during compilation).